# JOOQ : pojos in different directory

Tags: java, code-generation, jooq

I am going through JOOQ's GeneratorStrategy. I want to generate POJOs in different directory.

My requirement is, I have 3 maven modules, `A`, `B` and `shared`, plus `generated-resources` for JOOQ's generated files [so total 4]. Now, I want only `shared` module to use JOOQ's functionalities [so, I use `generated-resources` maven dependency only in `shared` ]. I want to restrict `Records` classes to be available in any of `A` or `B`, but they can talk to `shared` with POJOs.

So far I found out to change package. The `TargetDirectory` setters/getters are final, so are `AbstractGeneratorStrategy` `getFile`, `setFile` methods.

If there any automated way to achieve this, or am I asking too much?

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.8, there are only workarounds to achieve this. For example:

#### Run the code generator twice

You can run the code generator twice, once with only `<pojos>true</pojos>` and once with the rest.

There are some generated artefacts that you cannot get rid of (yet). You will then need to remove those artefacts from the POJOs in `shared`. There are Maven plugins for such file manipulation

#### Move the POJOs into a different module manually

You can also take all the POJOs after generating them, and move them to a different directory / module / project e.g. by using the [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html)